# How to override an implicit conversion in my scala test?

Tags: scala, unit-testing, mockito, implicit-conversion, scalatest

I am working on a scala test that tests the code which uses implicit conversion methods. I don't want to use those implicit conversions and would like to mock/override them in the test. Is it possible to do that ?

```
implicit class Typeconverter(objA: typeA) {
  def asTypeB = {
    // return a typeB object
  }
}

def methodA(request: typeA) {
  ...............
  request.asTypeB
  ...............
}
```

While testing methodA, I want to mock/override "asTypeB" instead of the actual one being called.

Comment: Can you please add code of what you are currently doing and what exactly you want to do

Answer (score 2):

As with any other dependency, you make `m` testable by passing it in.

```
def m(request: A)(implicit cv: A => B) = ???
```

Then the test can supply arbitrary conversions either explicitly or implicitly.

But an implicit inside the compiled method was resolved at compile time.

To supply a custom test version, supply a binary-compatible version of the conversion selected by implicit search. But that could be tricky and, to quote the other answer, doesn't sound like a good idea. If the implicit is neatly packaged, it might be feasible.

Answer (score 1):

That doesn't sound like a good idea, but if you have a method or function with the same name and type as the original implicit in the current scope, it will override the previous one. This trick is used by e.g. rapture https://github.com/propensive/rapture/blob/dev/json-argonaut/shared/src/main/scala/rapture/json-argonaut/package.scala#L21 https://github.com/propensive/rapture/blob/dev/json-circe/shared/src/main/scala/rapture/json-circe/package.scala#L21

Comment: Is it not a good idea because we are skipping some part of code that is being tested ?

Comment: I don't think the question is about compiling methodA, but about testing it.

Comment: For implicits shadowing to kick in, type doesn't have to be exactly the same, it only must be applicable for implicit application. Imports are shadowed by their short name, and the last imported wins. E.g. `import A.asTypeB; import B.asTypeB` - the second import will shadow the first one.